# Behind the Scenes with Arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

C# handles arrays much differently than C or C++ does.  It treats them as an object for one thing, although they do have a fixed size.  So I have some questions about arrays in C#:

1. If I create an array `new int[10]` will the Length property be guaranteed to be 10 or does C# try and resize the array if I get close to filling it up?
2. If I need to resize the array, do I have to create a new one with a larger size and then copy over each element in the array, or can I simply add more space without copying the elements over.

EDIT: it looks like you can use `Array.Copy` to copy the array over.

1. The List collection in C# seems like a dynamically sized array (maybe a mix between arrays and linked lists).  If I use a List instead of an array, can I control its size? (i.e. force it to be length 10, then set its size to 20 if I need more space)

Comment: Use Array.Resize instead of Array.Copy for #2. I believe it does do a copy underneath anyways.

Comment: If I have an array that isn't completely filled (ex `{1, 2, null, 4, null}` ) will Array.Resize condense it in addition to resizing or leave the spaces in (just add more slots to the end).

Comment: @jtfairbank, that array *is* filled. It happens to be filled with null, assuming the array is `int?[]`. (An array `int[]` would be filled with 0s, elements could not hold `null`).

Comment: @jtfairbank No, it will leave the `null` values there. The "slots" will be whatever default(T) is anyway, in reference types that means `null`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I create an array new int[10] will the Length property be guaranteed to be 10 or does C# try and resize the array if I get close to filling it up?

It'll be 10. Always 10.

> If I need to resize the array, do I have to create a new one with a larger size and then copy over each element in the array, or can I simply add more space without copying the elements over.

You need to resize it and copy. There are some helper methods that make this easier, like [`Array.Resize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) - but make no mistake that it is creating a new array and using `Array.Copy` to put everything there. If you need a resizable collection, use `List<T>`.

> The List collection in C# seems like a dynamically sized array (maybe a mix between arrays and linked lists). If I use a List instead of an array, can I control its size? (i.e. force it to be length 10, then set its size to 20 if I need more space).

The size is controlled automatically. It will grow when needed. There is a constructor overload to accept the initial size. Internally, it also uses an array that is being resized when needed. When it's filled; it grows by double of its current capacity, and copies everything in the new underlying array in the list. But all that magic happens behind the scenes. If you want to manually resize the internal array of the `List<T>`, set the `Capacity` property to the number of items.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, the Length will be 10.

2) Yes you have to create another one and copy the members. The Array class provides a method for that but you can't avoid the copying.

3) A list is indeed more convenient. You control its length (Count) by adding or removing members.

As a consequence, arrays are used less frequently in C#. We prefer `List<T>` classes (which could be using arrays under the covers). But they do incur some overhead.

Use arrays for low-level or fixed-size problems. Also there are no good (fast) multi-dim List classes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, arrays defined like that have a fixed size.
2. Yes, if you wish to extend you'll have to create a new Array
3. Yes, you can specify an initial capacity, with all values initializes to the default of the type stored. Extending happens automatically.

Comment: About #3: This answer could be interpreted to say that setting the initial capacity also initializes values up to that capacity, which is incorrect. The capacity and the content are related in that the capacity must be at least big enough to hold the content. However, setting an initial capacity does not mean the content is prefilled and *usable*. An example, `var list = new List<int>(10); int willThrowException = list[9];` Index 9 is out of range.

Answer (score 2):

1. No
2. If you don't know the size of the array, and if the collection has to grow, use a [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead.  A List uses an array internally, but the List takes care of resizing the array if necessary.
3. The List will grow automatically as needed.  You can set it's initiali [`Capacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) though.

Answer (score 1):

1. C# creates array of length 10 and don't resize it.
2. You can use list, you can't resize arrays.
3. Yes you can set list [Capacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2.aspx).

> Capacity is the number of elements that the List(Of T) can store
>   before resizing is required, while Count is the number of elements
>   that are actually in the List(Of T).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are of a fixed size. If you want to change the size of an array, allocate a new one, and copy the items into it using Array.Copy (or Array.Resize).

It is recommended to use `List<T>` instead, if you are regularly doing this. That handles all the resizing for you. You can specify an initial capacity when you create the list, but if you add more than the capacity the backing array is automatically resized to fit the extra items.

Answer (score 1):

quick n dirty ;)

- If I create an array new int[10] will the Length property be guaranteed to be 10 or does C# try and resize the array if I get close to filling it up?

NO

- If I need to resize the array, do I have to create a new one with a larger size and then copy over each element in the array, or can I simply add more space without copying the elements over.

YES

- The List collection in C# seems like a dynamically sized array (maybe a mix between arrays and linked lists). If I use a List instead of an array, can I control its size? (i.e. force it to be length 10, then set its size to 20 if I need more space)

If you construct your list without a capacity it will grow. You can set the maximum size using the constructor like...

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(10);
```